# How to make a "subLayout" fixed in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating an app that gets some values, you click in a button and it returns some other values and this views are distributed in 2 subLayouts of a bigger vertical `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.4">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/number1" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/number2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/number1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calc!"
            android:id="@+id/calcButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/number2"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Answer"
            android:id="@+id/Answer" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that when I click on my `EditText` and the keyboard appears the answer's `TextView` goes up with the keyboard and "overrides" my button (the entire `RelativeLayout` follows the keyboard), there's a way of setting the `RelativeLayout` fixed so that it stays where it is mean to be?
Here what is happening:

[image]
There's a way of fixing that RelativeLayout?

Comment: Have you specified windowSoftInputMode in Manifest??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" for the activity in Android Manifest file.

Comment: adjustPan should have done the trick. Try using "adjustNothing"

Comment: Setting this in Android Manifest you mean adding in the `<application>` tag right? Like `<application android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">`. And after that do I need to rebuild the application or something?

Comment: not for the application tag. Please check https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

Comment: Ok, it's not working... adjustPan neither adjustNothing. what should i do so?

Comment: There's no way of setting the entire layout fixed??